# AirFlow: Setting environment variable and environment in AirFlow task

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, airflow

I am currently trying to automate a data pipeline which consists of different scripts. Many of these scripts rely on the setting of an environment variable called `DB_URL`.
In the python scripts this variable is read in via `os.getenv('DB_URL', None)`.

It is possible for me to execute a DAG by using a BashOperator and specifying `DB_URL` directly in front of the execution of the script:

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'Hans Bambel',
'depends_on_past': False,
'email': ['hans-bambel@example.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 0,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='get_data_from_testdb',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Gets some data from the DB specified in the connection "test_db"',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 2, 24)
) as dag:
    connection = BaseHook.get_connection("test_db")
    db_url = 'postgresql://' + str(connection.login) + ':' + str(connection.password) + \
             '@' + str(connection.host) + ':' + str(connection.port) + '/' \
             + str(connection.schema)

    test_db_call = BashOperator(
        task_id='test_db_call',
        bash_command=f'export DB_URL={db_url}; /path/to/my/conda/environment/python /path/to/my/scripts/db_connection_test.py'
    )
```

But I would like to set up `DB_URL` once for all scripts that would use the same env variable like this:

```
with DAG(
        dag_id='get_data_from_testdb',
        default_args=default_args,
        description='Gets some data from the DB specified in the connection "test_db"',
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime(2021, 2, 24)
    ) as dag:
        connection = BaseHook.get_connection("test_db")
        db_url = 'postgresql://' + str(connection.login) + ':' + str(connection.password) + '@' + str(connection.host) + ':' + str(connection.port) + '/' + str(connection.schema)

        set_db_env = BashOperator(
            task_id='set-dburl',
            bash_command=f'export DB_URL={db_url}'
        )

        # activate_myenv = BashOperator(
        #     task_id='activate-conda-environment',
        #     bash_command='source activate myenv'
        # )

        test_db_call = BashOperator(
            task_id='test_db_call',
            bash_command=f'/path/to/my/conda/environment/python /path/to/my/scripts/db_connection_test.py'
        )
        set_db-env >> test_db_call
```

Additionally, I would like to activate my conda environment beforehand (as prepared by the `activate_myenv`-task), but I get the following error when adding it to the DAG:

```
[2021-02-25 17:07:12,923] {bash.py:158} INFO - Running command: source activate carex
[2021-02-25 17:07:12,932] {bash.py:169} INFO - Output:
[2021-02-25 17:07:12,942] {bash.py:173} INFO - bash: activate: No such file or directory
[2021-02-25 17:07:12,943] {bash.py:177} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
```

I expected that each DAG is run in isolation, but not each task as well. Therefore, I expected my  second DAG to work as well.
Is there something I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

When you make any change to a unix shell's environment, such as creating a new
variable, that change is propagated down to child processes, but never up to
the shell's parent. That's how Unix shells work.

So when your BashOperator does an "export DB_URL=...", that changes the shell
that is running the **set_db_env** task, but as soon as that task finishes, its
modified environment is gone, and with it the DB_URL variable you created. The next task
**test_db_call** inherits the same environment that **set_db_env** started out
with, not the one it changed.

To make DB_URL available for all scripts, you can define it *before* the
airflow processes are run, typically in the `.bashrc` file of the user running
the airflow process. This way your shell script can directly access the
variable's value in the usual way.

Or you might use Airflow's "variables": in the Airflow UI, menu `Admin / Variables`, define key=DB_URL, set the value, and save it. Then you can use the
mechanism described in the [Concepts
docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html) with
the jinja templates:

```
bash_command='echo {{ var.value.DB_URL }}'
```

to access the variable's value using the double brackets syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I expected as much, but I thought that all tasks of a DAG are run in the same environment and therefore when a preceding task modifies it the subsequent task is able to use the modified environment. But this could be problematic when tasks are run in parallel (even though that should be the problem of the person who set the DAG up).
I want to be flexible and use AirFlow dynamically for defining the variable, therefore setting the env beforehand is not desirable. The second proposition is basically already done in my code above as you can see with the Hook for security.